# Is it possible to stop the plugin resetting without a config.yml?

Tags: java, bukkit

I have a plugin where you can create a warp. However, when you reload the plugin, the warp is gone. If I put them in the `config.yml`, it doesn't work.

Is it possible to stop the deletion of warps on reload without a `config.yml`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yup, technically it would only work with a Database or files stored on a server.Perhaps you don't want to pay for this so I'd recommend using a config file

Comment: You don't have to pay to host a MySQL database, and a lot of server owners will prefer having it over a config file if there is a lot of data stored

Comment: But some plugins can take advantage over situations when the server is offline or network is unavailable . You can also share your settings or whatever else easier when you can just copy a config file rather than exporting mysql stuff and so on

Comment: While this is true if the plugin is only used on small servers with a low amount of warps, its still free to host a MySQL server (other than the *tiny* increase in an energy bill), and data is also accessed faster

Comment: Just run the mysql tasks in a [Bukkit async thread using `runTaskAsynchronously()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#runTaskAsynchronously(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin)), and run the Bukkit methods on [the main thread using `runTask()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#runTask(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin)) - Easier isn't always better

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do this.

When the plugin is loaded, most (if not all) of the data is stored on [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory), and when the plugin stops, the data is deallocated, allowing for other applications to use the RAM.

You have to write the data that used to be on the ram to the disk to make sure it isn't deleted, and the only way to do this is by either [using a database such as MySQL](https://bukkit.org/threads/using-mysql-in-your-plugins.132309/), or a file such as the `config.yml`

```
YamlConfiguration config = plugin.getConfig();
config.set("warps." + warpname, serializedWarpLocation);
```

Then, in your `onDisable()`

```
plugin.saveConfig();
```